# capistrano won't run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I'm using chef and capistrano to create a server and later deploy my code. As I'm new to capistrano I took a tutorial from [here](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/) and made some minor changes in order to get it going for me.

Whatever I do, I just cant get a `bundler install` to run on the remote server. Because of that there is no rake and the process stops at the `assets:precompile`. [A github repo containing the code](https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template).

Am I trying something that I shouldn't do?

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I'm only getting an error when it gets to rake assets:precompile. At that point it complains that rake is not installed. Gem list shows that no gems are installed at all, except Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with an additional task that explicitly runs `bundle install`. After that I still got an exception: `stdout: Nothing written`. I needed to add `, raise_on_non_zero_exit: false`
to be able to continue. Is anybody has a real `test()` to see if `bundle install` ran successfully I would be interested.

```
namespace :bundle do

  desc "run bundle install and ensure all gem requirements are met"
  task :install do
    on roles(:app) do
        execute "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle install  --without=test", raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
    end
  end

end
```